# How to add commas or space for every 4 digits in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

My case is a little special, I need to insert space or comma for every 4 digits.

Example:

`18686305
1868,6305 or 1868 6305`

How can I do in swift 4?

Comment: Well, which is it? Comma or space? What should the output be for `18986` be? Impossible to help you without an unambiguous clear spec.

Comment: Use `NumberFormatter` to ensure a number is properly formatted for a given user's locale.

Comment: Sorry for the vague requirement. Both cases need to be supported. A user can decide between these two formats.

Answer (score 3):

A `NumberFormatter` is designed to convert numerical values to `String` values based on a pre-defined format. In your case, the following will insert grouping separators every four digits:

```
import Foundation

let groupingSeparator = "," // determined based on user input, as per the question

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.positiveFormat = "####,####"
formatter.negativeFormat = "-####,####"
formatter.groupingSeparator = groupingSeparator

if let string = formatter.string(from: 18686305) {
    print(string) // prints "1868,6305"
}
```

The `positiveFormat` and `negativeFormat` variables follow the [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-numbers.html#Number_Format_Patterns).

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work in Swift 4.0. I got an error "Value of type 'NumberFormatter' has no member 'format' from the compiler.

Comment: The `format` property of `NumberFormatter` is only available for macOS, not iOS.

Comment: Yes... I'm developing for iOS, not macOS. Thanks for @LeoDabus, it's working after changing the format to "positiveFormat".

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you, I've updated my answer to reflect this platform discrepancy.